# Uniswap USDC=> ETH exchange

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, ethers.js

Trying to exchange USDC to ETH vith Uniswap and Ethers, but getting errors all the time.

```
async function swapUsdcToEth(amount, walledAddress) {
  const usdc = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48');
  const eth = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2');
  const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(usdc, eth);
  const route = new Route([pair], usdc);
  const amountIn = new TokenAmount(usdc, amount);
  const trade = new Trade(route, amountIn, TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
  const slippageTolerance = new Percent('50', '10000');
  const value = ethers.BigNumber.from(trade.inputAmount.raw.toString()).toHexString();
  const amountOutMin = ethers.BigNumber.from(trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw.toString()).toHexString();
  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20;
  const uniswapRouterV2Address = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D';
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/b9fkdmkdkdv4937b52ea9637cf1d1bd');
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(walledAddress, provider);
  const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
    uniswapRouterV2Address,
    ['function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],
    signer
  );
  try {
    const tx = await uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(value, amountOutMin, [walledAddress], walledAddress, deadline);
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log('transaction was mined in block', receipt.blockNumber);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Receiving errors like that: ' Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit '. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like possibly a few things. Have you approved your token to be spent by the router?
Also I'm not seeing any gas settings in there

here is a working version that I have modified to make work ( This is setup to test on a mainnet fork, however it's using live data (as the AlphaRouter is only for mainnet live so the live data and the fork data will change with time and cause trade errors, so reset fork before using)

to make main net only take out local provider and change all providers to main net provider.

USE WITH CAUTION, I'M NOT PERFECT AND GUARANTEE NOTHING : Check slippage and all variables

This is built As a TOKEN to TOKEN  Exact_Input swap with WETH deposit of 1 ETH.
To use ETH you can remove Weth deposit and token in approval and use the BigNumber.from(typedValueParsed) as the value of the transaction instead of 0

As I don't know EtherJS to well the Gas Price and Gas Limit for the Deposit and approval is a flat 100 gwei & 300k Limit, and should be modified for current network gas price and estimated gas Limit.

```
import { AlphaRouter } from '@uniswap/smart-order-router'
import { Token, CurrencyAmount } from '@uniswap/sdk-core'
import { JSBI, Percent } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";


const V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45";

const TokenInput = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

const TokenOutput = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";


const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/");
const web3 = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");

const privateKey = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey,web3);
const address = wallet.address;

import * as fs from 'fs';

let UniV3RouterAbi = fs.readFileSync('NewUniRouter.json');
const V3routerAbi = JSON.parse(UniV3RouterAbi);

let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

let WETHAbij = fs.readFileSync('WETHAbi.json');
const WETHAbi = JSON.parse(WETHAbij);

async function log(inpt){
    console.log(inpt);
    console.log("");
}

async function TokBal(tokens){
    var ERC20contract =  new ethers.Contract(tokens, ERC20, web3);
    var myERC20bal = await ERC20contract.balanceOf(wallet.address);
    return myERC20bal;
}

async function Deposit(amt){
    var WethC =  new ethers.Contract(TokenInput, WETHAbi, web3);
    var datac = await WethC.populateTransaction["deposit"]();
    var ncn = await wallet.getTransactionCount();

    const transaction = {
      data: datac.data,
      nonce: ncn,
      to: TokenInput,
      value: BigNumber.from(amt),
      from: wallet.address,
      gasPrice: '0x174876e800',
      gasLimit: '0x493e0',
    };

    const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx);
    log(txHash.hash);
}

async function Approve(Toked, amt){
    var WethC =  new ethers.Contract(Toked, ERC20, web3);
    var datac = await WethC.populateTransaction["approve"](V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amt);
    var ncn = await wallet.getTransactionCount();

    const transaction = {
      data: datac.data,
      nonce: ncn,
      to: Toked,
      value: BigNumber.from("0"),
      from: wallet.address,
      gasPrice: '0x174876e800',
      gasLimit: '0x493e0',
    };

    const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx);
    log(txHash.hash);
    var appFor = await WethC.callStatic.allowance(wallet.address, V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
    log("Approved : "+appFor.toString());
}


const router = new AlphaRouter({ chainId: 1, provider: web3Provider });
const WETH = new Token(
  router.chainId,
  '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  18,
  'WETH',
  'Wrapped Ether'
);

const USDC = new Token(
  router.chainId,
  '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
  6,
  'USDC',
  'USD//C'
);

const typedValueParsed = '1000000000000000000';
const wethAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(WETH, JSBI.BigInt(typedValueParsed));

const IO = "Exact_Input"
const TradeType = IO == "Exact_Input" ? 0 : 1;


const route = await router.route(
  wethAmount,
  USDC,
  TradeType,
  {
    recipient: wallet.address,
    slippageTolerance: new Percent(5, 100),
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000 +1800)
  }
);

var Ebal = await web3.getBalance(wallet.address);
log("Wallet Balance : "+Ebal.toString());

var tbal = await TokBal(TokenOutput);
log("Token Out Balance : "+tbal.toString());

await Deposit("1000000000000000000");
await Approve(TokenInput,"1000000000000000000");
var tbalW = await TokBal(TokenInput);
log("Token In Balance : "+tbalW.toString());

log(`Quote Exact In: ${route.quote.toFixed(wethAmount.currency === WETH ? USDC.decimals : WETH.decimals)}`);
log(`Gas Adjusted Quote In: ${route.quoteGasAdjusted.toFixed(wethAmount.currency === WETH ? USDC.decimals : WETH.decimals)}`);


var nc = await wallet.getTransactionCount();


const transaction = {
  data: route.methodParameters.calldata,
  nonce: nc,
  to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
  value: BigNumber.from(0),
  from: wallet.address,
  gasPrice: BigNumber.from(route.gasPriceWei),
  gasLimit: BigNumber.from(route.estimatedGasUsed).add(BigNumber.from("50000")),
};


const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);


const PretxHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(signedTx);


const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx)
log(txHash.hash);

var Ebal = await web3.getBalance(wallet.address);
log("Wallet Balance : "+Ebal.toString());

var tbal = await TokBal(TokenOutput);
log("Token Out Balance : "+tbal.toString());

var tbalW = await TokBal(TokenInput);
log("Token In Balance : "+tbalW.toString());
```

to get ETH use this in place of the output token

```
outPutAddress === WETH9[chainId].address ? nativeOnChain(chainId) : outPutToken,
```

EDIT>>>>>>>>>>
modified for new versions

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import {AlphaRouter, ChainId, SwapType, nativeOnChain} from '@uniswap/smart-order-router'
import { TradeType, CurrencyAmount, Percent, Token } from '@uniswap/sdk-core'
import { TickMath } from '@uniswap/v3-sdk';
import JSBI from 'jsbi';
import bn from 'bignumber.js'

async function main() {
  const MY_ADDRESS = "<ADDRESS>";
  const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<RPC_KEY>')

  const router = new AlphaRouter({ chainId: 1, provider: web3Provider });
  
  const WETH = new Token(
    1,
    '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
    18,
    'WETH',
    'Wrapped Ether'
  );

  const USDC = new Token(
    ChainId.MAINNET,
    '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
    6,
    'USDC',
    'USD//C'
  );

  const AAVE = new Token(
    ChainId.MAINNET,
    '0x7Fc66500c84A76Ad7e9c93437bFc5Ac33E2DDaE9',
    18,
    'AAVE',
    'AAVE'
  );

  const options = {
      recipient: MY_ADDRESS,
      slippageTolerance: new Percent(10, 1000),
      deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 1800),
      type: SwapType.SWAP_ROUTER_02,
    }
  const typedValueParsed = '10000000000000000000'
  
  const route = await router.route(
      CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(
        AAVE,
        typedValueParsed.toString()
      ),
      nativeOnChain(ChainId.MAINNET),
      TradeType.EXACT_INPUT,
      options
    )

  console.log(`Quote Exact In: ${route.quote.toFixed(route.quote.currency.decimals)}`);
  console.log(`Gas Adjusted Quote In: ${route.quoteGasAdjusted.toFixed(route.quote.currency.decimals)}`);
  console.log(`Gas Used USD: ${route.estimatedGasUsedUSD.toFixed(2)}`);
  console.log(route.methodParameters.calldata);
}

main()
```